# Not seeing how the derivative is an anti-Hermitian matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

It looks perfectly Hermitian to me. Consider an infinite continuous delta matrix, with a continuous index $m$ running along the rows and an index $n$ running along the columns.

So this matrix is zero everywhere, except at the diagonals $\delta (k,k)$, where it looks like the limit of a Gaussian curve.

Consider two points near the diagonal element $\delta (k,k)$ : $\delta (k-h,k)$ and $\delta (k, k-h)$. We will compute the derivatives of the delta matrix at these two points.

$$\frac{d}{dm}\delta (k-h,k)=\frac{\delta (k,k)-\delta(k-h,k)}{h}$$

Since $\delta (k-h,k)$ is an off-diaognal element which approaches 0, we get the derivative as $\frac{\delta (k,k)}{h}$

Similarly,

$$\frac{d}{dn}\delta (k,k-h)=\frac{\delta (k,k)-\delta(k,k-h)}{h}$$

which is again $\frac{\delta (k,k)}{h}$

This means $\delta '(k-h,k)=\delta'(k,k-h)$, which means the derivative is Hermitian. Where does this analysis go wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I just figured that I have to differentiate both elements with respect to the same index. This is because, when the derivative matrix acts on a function, it is supposed to give the derivative of the function with respect to some fixed index. So we must differentiate the basis vectors with that same index to get the derivative matrix.

In the post, I differentiated the first element with respect to $m$, but the other with respect to $n$. If I differentiate both with respect to $n$, I get the the two derivatives as negatives of each other, which proves anti-Hermitity